# Magento 2 : Need to put coupon form and proceed to check-out button outside cart-summary

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, shopping-cart, custom-theme

Currently I have below layout in my cart page. I need to put coupon form and proceed to checkout button outside cart-summary. Please check the second image for what I need. If anyone having knowledge regarding it then please help.Thanks!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your checkout_cart_index.xml file? Have you added theme in your website?

Comment: I have done with above requirement. By the way, thanks for you time. @ZealousWeb